# AS3 Anti Aliasing of a rotated bitmap

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

When rotating a bitmap with actionscript, the edges are jagged and not properly anti-aliased.

How do you force anti-aliasing of the bitmap ?

```
this.stage.quality = StageQuality.BEST; // Tried this, but seems useless 
var imgFromLib = new imgFromLib ();
imgFromLib.rotation = 30;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

imgFromLib should be castable to Bitmap; Bitmap has **smoothing** and **pixelSnapping** properties. Maybe this helps.

Comment: imgFromLib is actually a MovieClip and I can't change it to Bitmap because of other implementations...